# iOS Camera Programming - How to get maximum resolution images in the didOutputSampleBuffer callback

Tags: ios, camera

I have this camera App where I'd like to get the max resolution image in the didOutputSampleBuffer callback. Right now all the frames I receive in the callback are 852 x 640 (I am using an iPhone 4 for testing). Only when I request for a still image capture (via captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection) do I get one - and only one - frame corresponding to the actual image captured in the highest resolution of the device - 2592x1936.

Is it possible to set things up so that I constantly receive frames of resolution - 2592x1936 in didOutputSampleBuffer? Then I would like to save some of these frames as images in the callback without having to go through captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection to capture an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video output can't support the full resolution that you see when capturing still images. Look at the table given in [Use Capture Outputs to Get Output from a Session](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW26) for a list of supported resolutions.

If you want to change the resolution set the appropriate setting on your camera session like so:

```
cameraSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
```

Note that `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` isn't possible with video capture.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that answers it :)